Website Publish compiling all dlls into one file
.NET8
Is it yet possible (as in Winapps true)
To create one file for all dlls in a WEB application
For example Folder Refs created contains loads of dlls
We also use DevExpress which also has loads of dlls
Any advice appreciated thanks
tried this and compiled all dlls  true
inside the projname.csproj file - seemed to work but then get an IIS error
I know the dlls that I do not need is there a way of removing them from the csproj file pre publish - I tried a few things eg (but file still remained after publish)
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="DevExpress.AspNetCore.Spreadsheet.v23.2.dll" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>


As can be read in docs Single-file deployment, you can add following lines to your .csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>

Then it should produce single exe/dll file from your project.

Thanks - PublishSingleFile works fine for WinApps - not for WebApps - the RuntimeIdentifier i am already using to restrict to 64 bit.
What i need is a way to remove unwanted dlls from the Publish folder inside the csproj file - I have tried lots of things but cannot get rid of them
